# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: must be owner of function to_tsvector

Tags: python, django, postgresql, traceback

During the deployment I got an error on our project on "python manage.py migrate":

```
  File "/Users/paus/project/api/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 117, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.render(), schema_editor)
  File "/Users/paus/project/api/sn/migrations/0012_user_full_name_full_text.py", line 8, in create_index
    schema_editor.execute('ALTER FUNCTION to_tsvector(text) IMMUTABLE')
  File "/Users/paus/project/api/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/paus/project/api/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/paus/project/api/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/paus/project/api/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/paus/project/api/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: must be owner of function to_tsvector
```

How should I deal with it? Is it anything related to the Postgresql what we use? Where to fix it?

Thank you for advices!

Comment: Make sure you're running migrations as a database owner, i.e. your `settings.DATABASES` is set up accordingly.

Comment: I checked this case, user and password are the same.

Comment: Just to clarify: if you type `\l` in `psql` shell, the printed database owner is the same user as in your settings, right?

Comment: Probably, yes: 

 database            | user  | UTF8     | C       | C     | =Tc/user          +
                    |          |          |         |       | user=CTc/user